# Как поменять цвет кнопки в состоянии mousedown

Tags: javascript, css

Я поменял цвет при наведении мыши, при фокусе, но не могу поменять стандартный (синий) цвет, когда нажимаешь на кнопку, но клавишу не отпускаешь. Как я понял это состояние называется mousedown. По логике это решается просто чистым css

```
            <Button
              type='submit'
              disabled={isSubmitting}
              className='auth-button'
              onClick={() => {
                setLogInWindow(false)
              }}
            >Войти</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```css
button {
  background-color: red;
}

button:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: Может проблема в том, что у меня кнопка из react-bootstrap, ибо это не работало(

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в том, что кнопка из react-bootstrap и на нее был почему-то наложен стиль primary, который и давал синий цвет и не давал себя перебить. Проблему решил изменив этот стиль:

```
    button.auth-button.btn.btn-primary:active {
      background-color: #fbe200;
    }
```

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#specificity - приоритеты селекторов.

Comment: Рад, что Вы решили проблему, но в следующий раз описывайте исходные условия более подробно, так как предложеное Вам решение работает в поставленных Вами-же условиях.